# Can´t find my picture node insted I get null

Tags: javascript, html

I have my script before the closing body tag so that´s not the problem and my picture have the right id. But when I use console.log(albumCover) I get null instead of the picture node.

```
<img id="album_cover" src="space-160x160.jpg" alt="Kalliope Image">

const albumCover = document.querySelector("#album_cover");
songPick.addEventListener("change", audioImageSource);

function audioImageSource() {
    let option = document.querySelector("select").options;
    let indexImageSong = document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex;
    audio.src = songPick.value;
    console.log(option[indexImageSong].index);
    console.log(option[indexImageSong]);
    switch (option[indexImageSong].index) {
        case 0:
            console.log(albumCover);
            albumCover.src = 'space-160x160.jpg';
            break; 
        case 1:
            albumCover.src = 'friendly-alien-planet-160x160.jpg';
            break;
        case 2:
            albumCover.src = 'Soundscape-music-160x160.jpg';
            break;
        case 3:
            albumCover.src = 'soundscape-160x160.jpg';
            break;    
    }

}
```

Comment: So, does the code work and it just does not log or the other logic relating to albumCover is also not working?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: No it does not. I tried to change the album cover = const document.querySelector (img [alt = "Kalliope Image"] "), then it works. I wonder why Id does not work.

Comment: This works perfectly fine: `console.log('>>>', document.querySelector("#album_cover"))`. Also, you should not use `let` statements there (only use them in nested blocks when you dont want the variable to hoist to the top of the function - so replace `let option` with `var option` in this instance as you are manually hoisting themselves anyway by declaring them there).